# Setup WebDriver's profile automatically to open Excel files

Tags: c#, excel, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

I found solutions to silently download files (without Open/Save dialog) but can't find anything for setting up WebDriver profile automatically to open a file without saving.

Using Selenium and C#. The file is a .csv and here is my code:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
//set to automatically open file
profile.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);
profile.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile","text/csv,application/vnd.ms-excel,application/excel");
profile.SetPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
Instance = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Am I missing something with plugins?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by installing FF extension InlinedDisposition 2 and here is the updated code:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
try
{
    profile.AddExtension(@"E:\Firefox Extensions\InlineDisposition2.xpi");
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    throw new FileNotFoundException("Could not load required extensions, did you download them to the above location? ", e.Message);
}

//set to automatically open excel file
profile.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);
profile.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile", "application/octectstream,text/x-csv,text/csv,application/vnd.ms-excel");     

Instance = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

I believe the reason behind this was the fact that sometimes the website sends the wrong information about a file. And also, if the server sends the file with a generic content type then it won't work.

That add-on took care of this issue.

I hope this helps.